# PHP class_alias with var_dump as that class

Tags: php, class, alias

I'm working on a library to connect to the Eventbrite API. I've made it generic enough that a lot of the second level business objects are empty classes. Having said that, when I instantiate those objects, I would still like them to register as different classes. I thought `class_alias` would be the way to go, but it seems that the original class is what is returned when doing a `var_dump`.

Current:

```
<?php

namespace Project;

class_alias(
    '\\Project\\Classes\\Aliaser', 
    '\\Project\\Classes\\Attendee',
    true
);

use Project\Classes\Aliaser;
use Project\Classes\Attendee;

$attendee = new Attendee();
var_dump($attendee)
// Aliaser {}
```

What I'm shooting for:

```
$attendee = new Attendee();
var_dump($attendee);
// Attendee {}
```

I would really like to delete the empty classes in favor of the generic one while also having the new dynamically generated class be registered.

Is that possible without a serious performance hit?

Note: Prefer PHP 5.4 or greater, but PHP 7 is also good.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU: Because "GenericClass" is not as helpful to developers as "SpecicClass", but it's also confusing to have a bunch of classes that inherit from "GenericClass" and don't actually extend or override functionality.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your problem but I fail. You need "special classes" but you don't want them. It's confusing

Comment: Give me an example of an alias that would be helpful for you so I could think of a solution

Comment: From what I see you receive an object from the API that do not have sub-types,  so why would you need "special classes" for non-existing sub-types https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/response_formats/attendee/

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU: https://github.com/8fold/eventbrite-sdk-php/blob/develop/src/Classes/SubObjects/Question.php - take a look there (leaving out of question right now). The class is empty and most likely won't need to do anything beyond what its parent already does; therefore, it is an empty file. The path to get there is by getting an event `$event` then chaining there `$event->questions`. Is there a way to return an instance with the same namespace, but without the class file actually being there? If not, it's cool, more a curiosity.

Comment: It is possible, see my answer, but what you are asking is ilogical and pointless. I gave an answer only because what you are asking is possible but you should not create an empty class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of a class without puting the code to a file by using `eval`:

```
// define the class if it does not exists
if (!class_exists (\Eightfold\Eventbrite\Classes\ApiResource\Question::class)) {
    eval ( 'class Question extends \Eightfold\Eventbrite\Classes\ApiResource {} ');
}

//create instance
$instance = new \Eightfold\Eventbrite\Classes\ApiResource\Question ();
```

P.S. If you don't find another solution without `eval` then you should consider this quote:

> If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong
>   question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

Comment: Hmmmm...take the down vote is because there is a performance hit...??

Comment: I do not understand. Do you know other solution for creating a class without actually creating a file that contains the class?

Comment: The only thing that may go bad is that the class could already exist, so i've updated the answer

Comment: If you don't find another solution without `eval` then you should consider this quote: "If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the
wrong question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP"

Comment: I did not down vote it. Was curious why someone would.

Comment: There are all kind of people on SO. One of them search all the day the word "eval" and downvote. Probably.

Comment: I don't think there is another way to do this. Having said that, the addition of the Rasmus Lerdorf is wonderful - and probably accurate. :)

Comment: Thanks. I do not give solutions with `eval` unless there is no other way.